# SQL query several columns about the same field but diferent codes

Tags: sql

How can I create a query that has multiple counter columns for the same field?
I have a field called card_status that can have 7 different values.
I wanted to create a query that would display total values on the same row and not on 7 different rows.

Comment: Examples please... of data and desired results. We don't want to make assumptions.

Comment: Help us help you. Take a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59376602/edit) your question with additional detail.

Comment: Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: But I'd rather do `GROUP BY card_status`, and have the result in several rows. (Will be forward compatible if someone later adds another card_status values.)

Comment: If you use oracle you could check grouping sets

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN card_status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Count_of_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN card_status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Count_of_2,
       ...
       SUM(CASE WHEN card_status = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Count_of_7
    FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional count

**For example:**

```
SELECT col1, col2
, COUNT(CASE WHEN card_status = 'revoked' THEN card_status END) AS TotalRevoked
, COUNT(CASE WHEN card_status = 'requested' THEN card_status END) AS TotalRequested
, COUNT(CASE WHEN card_status = 'lost' THEN card_status END) AS TotalLost
-- add more
, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY col1, col2
ORDER BY col1, col2
```

This works on the principle that counting a column or expression doesn't count the NULL's